# Pymongo query: convert '_id': ObjectId('64467d4f561b67000140d133') to correct doc ID?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, bson

I'm using pymongo to query a collection by _id (generated from a timestamp) over a range. To do this I'll take the current time and round down to get the end_time_bson, and then subtract a couple of seconds from that to get the start_time_bson:

```
end_dt = datetime.utcnow().replace(minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0).
end_dt = ObjectId.from_datetime(end_dt)

start_dt = datetime.utcnow().replace(minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0) + timedelta(seconds = -2)
start_dt = ObjectId.from_datetime(start_dt)

query = {"_id": {"$gte": start_dt_bson, "$lt": end_dt_bson}}
```

This returns a few documents but the IDs of each are in this format:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('64467d4f561b67000140d133'), ... }
```

This `_id` does not correspond to any document in the collection. All documents in the collection are of a form:

```
{'_id': 'ee5885441', ... }
```

So I assume I'm missing something in the encoding/decoding process either in creating my query or in parsing my response.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: `'_id': 'ee5885441'` is not an ObjectId.

Comment: Correct. I think this may be really old data with a manually created _id. Trying to validate why querying for those longer ObjectIds returns nothing though.

Comment: Because query operators are case-sensitive, so ObjectId will never match String

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You get some documents with ObjectIds and you can't find them in the collection? If so, try querying them like this `db.collection.find({
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "XXX"
  }
})`

Comment: Also, with the query you mention, you can only get documents with objectIds, because these objectIds store the timestamp internally, if you have other documents where the id is just a string, your query will not work because there is no additional information there.